# Распознание текста в определенной области скана PDF в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, opencv, машинное-зрение

Есть скан документа в pdf формате. Как распознать текст в определенной области такого документа, точнее цифровой номер?
[image: Нужно распознать выделенное красным]

Comment: Нужен пример. Вопрос слишком абстрактный. Предлагаю закрыть

Comment: Добавил сам скан.

Comment: эта область всегда фиксирована?

Comment: +- 10 мм во все стороны, зависит от того как сканируются

Comment: @SacredSacred а может брать сразу весь текст, а потом вытаскивать нужное с помощью, например, регулярных выражений?

Comment: `pytesseract`, `re`...

Comment: А в QR коде, случайно, номер заказа не содержится?

Comment: Еще совет: найдите толстую жирную линию  вверху страницы (Хафа преобразование), а от ее координат уже можно найти номер.

Comment: Вам подходит моё решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Кропаете верхнюю часть картинки с запасом.
2. Template Matching слова "Заказ" см. https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html
3. Кропаете, исходя из найденого положения слова "Заказ" область с его номером.
4. P.S. Попробуйте распознать QR код, может быть номер заказа уже в нем содержится.
   P.P.S.
   **В QR коде такая информация: БЗ_3000-0052-06_13_1,2792_52_53_57_58**

Answer (score 3):

## Общие положения

Я опускаю момент, который раскрывает вопрос, как преобразовать pdf в картинку. Для этого есть [либы](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/). Пример использования можете посмотреть в аналогичном проекте, который занимается похожей задачей. Например, [здесь](https://github.com/Hedgehogues/HoChiMinh).

Есть 2 подхода:

- алгоритм на основе обучающей выборки (классическое машинное обучение)
- алгоритм на основе эвристик (old-school методы)

Нужно сразу понять, что не получится с полпинка решить эту задачу. Она исследовательская и придётся приложить некоторые усилия для её решения. Я дам вектор движения.

## Алгоритм на основе обучающей выборки

Скорее всего Вам не подойдёт первый, поскольку он сложнее в реализации, но более общий и совершенный в плане подхода. С другой стороны, есть много утилит, которые помогут разметить данные. Например, есть [толока](https://toloka.yandex.ru/requester/), [labelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) и другие. Как платные так и бесплатные. Далее, если Вы найдёте хорошую модель, то можно сделать очень неплохое решение крайне быстро. Но тут много деталей. Поэтому я опущу этот вопрос. И далее буду рассматривать только 2 подход.

Вы можете выбрать этот подход. Тогда Вам следует изучить как работать со свёрточными нейронными сетями и дообучать их. Но даже в этом случае, скорее всего, весь процесс будет состоять из нескольких этапов.

## Подход на основе эвристик

У нас есть несколько подзадач.

- Стандартизировать скан (избавиться от небольших поворотов)
- Выделить зону, в которой располагается объект (локализовать по пикселям место, где находится зона)
- Сегментировать объект
- Преобразовать объект в текст

### Стандартизировать скан

Предлагается каким-нибудь способом выровнять картинку. Это можно сделать опять же либо с помощью предварительной разметки данных. Либо же с помощью эвристик. Можно посчитать "гистограммы" изображений суммировать по вертикали и горизонтали изображения и на этой основе делать вывод, насколько следует повернуть картинку. Можно придумать другие подходы. Что-то похожее есть [тут](https://habr.com/ru/company/abbyy/blog/449524/).

### Выделить зону, в которой располагается объект

Взять с запасом пикселей и вырезать подизображение.

### Сегментировать объект

Аналогично, как рассказано выше, можно рассматривать изображение как матрицу и складывать по горизонтали и вертикали её по той же ссылке, что и [выше](https://habr.com/ru/company/abbyy/blog/449524/). А затем отделять подстроки друг от друга.

### Tesseract или другой распознователь

Я бы не советовал использовать tesseract, так как раньше он был неустойчив и часто сбоил. Сейчас я слышал иные отзывы. Возможно, что-то изменилось. Попробуйте. Но есть масса других решений, которые умеют распозновать цифры. Можете поискать на [гитхабе](https://github.com/search?q=digit%20recognition).